# manipulating the css in Wordpress blog

Tags: css, wordpress, web

I am developing the following wordpress blog to put into my site: http://moreformymac.com/blog/ I am new to CSS and HTML so making the wordpress blog match my website is taking all of my knowledge and then some.  for the life of me I can't find the css responsible for causing the main grey transparent content box to run into my navigation bar.  I just want to move the main content box down 50 px or so.

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools in any of the modern browsers to see which file is being referenced for the CSS for that element?

Comment: just tried that now but didn't have any luck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css,  line 1745

```
body .site {
padding: 0 40px;
padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
margin-top: 48px;
margin-top: 3.428571rem;
margin-bottom: 48px;
margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
```

adjsut the "margin-top" entries. (the first is for older browsers, the second for newer browsers)

Comment: Bingo! I tried messing around with that line before but I think I forgot to change the second one and I didn't work.  Thanks!